# Moving EC2 to another AZ but can't enter the field value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an RDS running in Region/AZ us-east-1f and an EC2 (after a reset to generate a new private key) running in us-east-1a. The EC2 can't reach the RDS and I think its because they're in different AZ's now. So I read this http://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-ec2-instance/  on how to move the EC2. But when I try and execute the automated script/page the region field will only accept us-east-1 and not the letter after the 1. How do I tell the script to put the EC2 in us-east-1f (so it will be able to reach the RDS)? Thank you.
Update: I'm now focused on making sure both RDS and EC2 are in the same VPC. The RDS is in the rds-launch-wizard VPC, and the EC2 is in a VPC I created. In order to change the RDS VPC you need to create a new subnet but I get an error message in doing that saying I need to select multiple AZ. I do select multiple AZ but the error message persists with the same message. This is frustrating.

Comment: This is more likely related to security groups than subnets. Your ec2 instance and RDS generally do not need to be in the same subnet, just the same VPC.

Comment: "But when I try and execute the automated script/page the region field will only accept us-east-1 and not the letter after the 1."  what autoamted script/page are you talking about?  If you're using the AWS Web console the networking section in "launch instance" lets you choose a subnet and thus an AZ, but the default is "no preference" so you have to edit and change that.  Explain what script you're using and maybe we can help you further

Comment: I can see my EC2 in the console but I can't connect. (I can ssh from my desktop though.) I also don't see any option for "launch instance". Under the Instance State button (top right) I can reboot the instance but there was no choice for AZ to reboot into. Where do you see "launch instance" in Networking? I see data about the network interface and a "Run Reachability Analyzer" button.

Comment: It would appear that you are complicating this whole matter. Rather than focussing on AZs, focus on your main objective. It would appear that your first objective is to **connect to the Amazon EC2 instance**, and then to allow software running on the EC2 instance to **connect to the Amazon RDS database**. Is this correct? If so, let's focus on connecting to the EC2 instance. Are you wanting connect via SSH or RDP? What happens when you try to connect? What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the EC2 instance? Is it in a public subnet? Let's get that working first.

Comment: Hi John. I can SSH to the EC2. On the console, under Security I have one security group I created. I also have several inbound rules and one outbound rule. What specifically are you looking for in the EC2's Security section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to AZ/VPC/network changes in an EC2 is that you need to stop the EC2 instance, create a new image (AMI), and then launch that new AMI. In launching the new AMI you will have the opportunity to select the VPC/AZ/subnet/security group etc.
In my case I had to set up a new set of inbound rules on the EC2 security group to allow SSH (port 22 only from my IP address) and HTTP (port 80) from all IPv4 addresses. And believe it or not, in the course of launching the new AMI an option appeared to "connect to an RDS" to which I agreed and my EC2 and RDS are now talking!

Answer (score 0):

> The EC2 can't reach the RDS and I think its because they're in different AZ's now

If it's in the same VPC it can communicate across subnets. ( If it's in a different VPC that would require peering or transit gateway and some routes).

I suspect your security group is at fault here.  If you're using a CIDR to allow access, you may have put in just one subnet's CIDR into the allowed inbound rules on the rds security group.  It's better to create a security group for your RDS clients, alllow that client security group in your RDs security group ingress rules, and associate the client SG  to instances that should access your RDS, that way IPs aren't relevant and you have finer grained access.

> But when I try and execute the automated script/page the region field will only accept us-east-1 and not the letter after the 1.

if you're RDS is not multi-AZ there's little benefit to putting its client in a different AZ, and cross AZ traffic does incur a cost so putting your instance in us-east-1f makes sense.

Based on your shared link (https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/automation/execute/AWSSupport-CopyEC2Instance?region=us-east-1) which should work for anyone once you're logged into AWS, there's an optional `SubnetId` parameter to the SSM action you're running that can be used to place the instance.

Comment: sorry to give you a non-answer posted as an answer but it was too big to fit in comment.  leave further details about exactly what process you're using to create the instance and maybe we can help you further

Comment: Yesterday it looked like the RDS & EC2 were in the same VPC but today it doesn't. Here is the script page that moves EC2: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/automation/execute/AWSSupport-CopyEC2Instance?region=us-east-1

Comment: To offer more insight though, I have added a new CIDR to the RDS VPC to allow my home SQL Workbench to connect but it is unreachable. So maybe something is wrong with the RDS...

Comment: But if there's extra charges in sending data between us-east-1a and us-east-1f that I can avoid by having them both in the same AZ then I might as well move the EC2 into the RDS's AZ right?

Comment: " I have added a new CIDR to the RDS VPC to allow my home SQL Workbench to connect but it is unreachable" that would only work if the RDS instance was on a public IP address, which is a configuration option when you create RDS instance

Comment: "But if there's extra charges in sending data between us-east-1a and us-east-1f that I can avoid by having them both in the same AZ then I might as well move the EC2 into the RDS's AZ right?" yes.  whether that means putting in the same subnet as RDS depends on whether RDS is public and whether your instance is public.

Comment: When I look at the RDS instance in the console and view Connectivity & Security there is a spot on the right that says Publicly accessible and under that is says Yes. So I think it is accessible and I used to use MySQL Workbench to connect to it but I can't anymore.

Comment: it's possible you IP address changed so a security group rule no longer applies to you.

Comment: Thank you erik258. Yes I have put in new inbound CIDR rules with the new IP address in a couple places... Maybe I didn't get them all?